# Xamarin Android How to do Scrollview with Percents Heights

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

Android views seem to be finicky. It seems like scroll view needs to be a height of:

> height ="wrap_content"

in order to function properly but this messes up because I was using weight sum before on the idea that it took the entire screen when it was match_parent. Is there anyway to still have percentages for items inside of the listview that is inside a scroll view? Or an alternative and if possible an example.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_weight="30" /> ...
```

here is just a sample as its pretty long. That image button Id like to take 30 or so percent of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this information no where. So dp stands for Density-independent Pixels. Basically they already scale properly to make it so all views will look the same based upon a percent from my understanding. Feel free if anyone has more information. I thought it stood for deca pixel.

So choosing height 500dp should look the same for all devices. As someone who doesn't have physical multiple devices I was leaning on always percentage in views, but it seems like this isn't entirely necessary for some cases.